# Drupal 7 Anti-concurrent editing fields

Tags: drupal-7

There are two modules:

- Conflict
- Content locking (anti-concurrent editing)

The above modules only work with nodes.
I'm looking for a similar way to make it work with:

- users accounts profile fields (e-mail, password and custom fields).

Comment: I think you need a custom development , you can improve content lock module (fork and add what you need into it) or create a new module